# Entity Framework 4.0 CTP5 One to One Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, code-first

Hi i am using CTP5 to map between two entities like that:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsManager { get; set; }
    public decimal Credit { get; set; }
    public int CreditAlertCount { get; set; }
    public decimal TelPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal CellPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> PhoneList { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}

public class UserType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserLevel { get; set; }
    public string TypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

//here is configurations

```
public class UserConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfig()
    {

        HasKey(c => c.Id);
        Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity).HasColumnName("ID");
        Property(c => c.InsertDate).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed).HasColumnName("INSERT_DATE");
        Property(c => c.IsManager).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed).HasColumnName("IS_MANAGER");
        Property(c => c.UserName).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired().HasColumnName("USER_NAME");
        Property(c => c.Password).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired().HasColumnName("USER_PASSWORD");
        Property(c => c.CellPrice).IsRequired().HasColumnName("CELL_PRICE");
        Property(c => c.TelPrice).IsRequired().HasColumnName("TEL_PRICE");
        Property(c => c.CreditAlertCount).IsRequired().HasColumnName("CREDIT_ALERT_COUNT");
        Property(c => c.Credit).IsRequired().HasColumnName("CREDIT");
        Property(c => c.UserTypeId).IsOptional().HasColumnName("USER_TYPE_ID");

        /*relationship*/
        HasRequired(p => p.UserType).WithMany().IsIndependent().Map(m => m.MapKey(p => p.Id, "USER_TYPE_ID"));

        ToTable("CRMC_USERS", "GMATEST");
    }
}

 public class UserTypeConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserType>
{
    public UserTypeConfig()
    {
        /*Identity*/
        HasKey(c => c.Id);
        Property(c => c.Id).HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity).HasColumnName("ID");

        /*simple scalars*/
        Property(s => s.TypeDescription).IsRequired().HasColumnName("DESCRITPION");
        Property(s => s.UserLevel).IsRequired().HasColumnName("USER_LEVEL");

        ToTable("CRMC_USER_TYPES", "GMATEST");
    }
}
```

What do i do wrong my User.UserType = null?

How to hell do i map this to work!?

I am dying here for 3 days to work it off.

I'm using DevArt Connection 6.058... some thing
Oracle 10g, C# EntityFramework 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've setup a *required* association between User and UserType, therefore you cannot have a User object without a UserType (i.e. User.UserType == null). To be able to do that you need to make 2 changes to your object model and fluent API:

1.Change the type of `UserTypeId` property to `int?`:

```
public int? UserTypeId { get; set; }
```

2.Remove the code from your fluent API that reads:
`HasRequired(p => p.UserType).WithMany().IsIndependent().Map(m => m.MapKey...`

You don't need any of those stuff. Everything will be configured by Code First based on convention for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it's doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: For some reason when i do Include it does build the correct query to retrieve the right entities, but when i do a simple FindById(int id) it's fails and return UserType == null.
Sorry for the late comment.

Comment: Hi, i have solved this issue by adding the ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true; 

Thank you very much for your answer, can you please reffer me to anyu of the blogs that you written with the Mapping issues?

Comment: Sure, but first I need to understand your issue. Please show your updated solution that works now. *ProxyCreationEnabled* flag is set to true by default so I am not sure how that solve your problem.

Comment: I have set this one to false, didn't wanted the proxy to be enabled.